# Excel formula to return string between first static character and one of TWO possible 2nd characters?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a formula that looks at Cell A1 on a worksheet called "FolderDataImport" (copied down the whole column).

```
=MID(LEFT(FolderDataImport!A1,FIND("(",FolderDataImport!A1)-1),FIND("- ",FolderDataImport!A1)+2,LEN(FolderDataImport!A1))
```

It selects and returns any data/text after the character "-" and before the character "(".

This works perfectly for example text 1 below and it would return "An Example Text"

Example Text 1
**"This Is - An Example Text (Sometimes formatted) [Like This] (Which I Will) Call Example 1"**

but some times the data it is looking at is formatted as shown in example text 2 where the is no text enclosed in left and right Parenthesis BEFORE the character "[" meaning it returns everything between the "-" and the (  like "Another Example [But Is Different]"

Example Text 2
**"This Is - Another Example [But Is Different]  (Which I Will) Call Example 2"**

There may be a better way of doing this but what I need the formula to do is starting from the first character on the left find the "-" and then IF it finds a "(" return the characters
(as in my example text 1) "*An Example Text*" BUT if it finds a "[" before it finds a "(" (as shown in text example 2, then it only returns the text between "-" and "[" which, using my text example 2, would be "*Another Example*".

This added complication is beyond my somewhat lacking skills?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+2,MIN(FIND({"[","("},A1))-FIND("-",A1)-3)
```

I guess without Microsoft365 it would be an CSE-entered formula.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. array formulas are like "dark Magic" to me.